# How to get information from a clicked element with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a list which displays thumbnails and the name of the film next to each one. For each new thumbnail I make this call:

```
$("#thumb").append('<li><img id="amatx" src='+value+' /></li><p id="titol">'+titl+'</p>');
```

***thumb*** is the divisor in which the thumbnails and titles are listed. ***value*** contains the link to the thumbnail while ***titl*** contains the title. I get all this information from an API. Now I want to create a listener that when I click a thumbnail or a title it displays the name of the film. This is what I got by now:

```
App.prototype.listenerFilms = function(){
        $("#amatx").on('click', function(evt){

        });
};
```

I really don't know how to get the information because all the images and titles got the same id's... can someone help me please?

Comment: You can't re-use the same id value. They must be unique. You can re-use class values however.

Comment: Edit: @Pointy has already guided you in the right direction. class="my_amatx" and have the same class attribute that enables you to access the elements. Then to further access the p tag use child or next the appropriate selector to retrieve the title.

Comment: Just use classes instead of IDs and use a delegated event handler (see answer below). This will solve both your problems.

Comment: If you cannot figure out what I mean in the example, please provide  your page/HTML in the question so I can mockup a working example (e.g. in a JSFiddle).

Comment: Yeah now the listener works but I can't display what I want... I commented in your answer TrueBlueAussie.

Comment: Answer updated with code/JSFiddle to cover your comment too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use classes instead of IDs, as IDs must be unique (jQuery will only match the first element with a given ID).

`$("#thumb").append('<li><img class="amatx" src='+value+' /></li><p class="titol">'+titl+'</p>');`

2. As you have dynamic elements, use a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor element

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.amatx', function(){
     // Listener code here
});
```

This will work for elements that only exist at event time (and not just at event registration time). it listens for events (in this case click) bubbling up to the ancestor, *then* applies the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble-chain, *then* calls the function only on any matching elements that caused the event.

**Note:** `document` is the default if no other element is closer/convenient to attach a delegated event handler to. Never use `body` for delegated events as it can have a calculated height of 0 depending on styling and will then not get click events. Stick to `document` as the default`.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5dsqdq5h/

Regarding your comment below, you need to search up from the clicked element, then find the next `titol` element *beside it*.

Comment: Ok now the listener is working yay!! But I don't know what do I have to write to display the name of the films. I tried this:
`console.log($(this).find('p#titol').text());`
but is not working

Comment: Please show your full code and HTML. The example given does not attempt to do much. You will need something like `$(this).closest('li').next('.titl').text();` as the clicked element is beside the title.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this because it's a lot of code and stuff... but the part about this is a simple div (`<div id="thumb"></div>`) and the reading from the API and the call I make for each thumbnail/title... What you said now didn't work but I bet we almost got this

Comment: "It's a lot of code and stuff" is never a valid excuse (and my example JSFiddle works just fine thank you) :) If you can provide better example HTML *in your question* I will be happy to make a better answer to match it.

Comment: Hey sorry, it works!! But it's not happening what I expected, I don't want to change the name of the film but getting it when I click the thumbnail or the title. I tried this: $(this).closest('li').next('.titol').text("yay"); and now when I click the thumbnail the title changes to "yay" but what I want is to print the name of the film in console. What is written inside "titol" class paragraph.

Comment: So just use `console.log($(this).closest('li').next('.titol').text());` Note: the '.titol' in `next()` is not actually needed. That is just for robustness.

Comment: Yeah! It worked! I did also a listener for when I click on paragraph. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When you enter in the click event, you can use the $(this) element.

And use class names instead of ids.

So:

```
App.prototype.listenerFilms = function(){
    $("#amatx").on('click', function(evt){
        console.log($(this).find('p#titol').text());
    });
};
```

Comment: All pointless as you cannot have duplicate IDs. jQuery will only ever return the first one. Suggest you update your code to match your comment.

Comment: Me too.. See above :)

Comment: It's still not working... I was wondering if I have to add something to make the elements "clickable", I mean the html is this:
`<div id="llistaPelis">
  <div id="thumb"></div>
 </div>`

maybe something is missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#thumb").on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(target.hasClass('amatx')) {
        console.log(target.closest('li').next('.titol').text());
    }    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g93wmwu2/)

Comment: If this is your answer, please provide an explanation of how this code solves the problem outlined in the answer. Code without an explanation is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. See [answer].